# What happens in C when I take the address of a pointer?

Tags: c

I have a sample program as follows:

```
int testPointer(int * intArray, int * ptr) {
  printf("%i\n", intArray);
  printf("%i\n", ptr);
  printf("%lu\n", &intArray);
  printf("%lu\n", &ptr);
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int result = testPointer((int *) 0x1, (int *) 0x2);
  return 0;
}
```

Typical output would be:

```
1
2
3212962484
3212962480
```

The first two lines are always the same and I understand how they are produced.  The third and fourth lines vary on each run but the value on the fourth line is always four less than the value on the third line. How do I decipher these values?  What do they represent and why is the last line always four less than the third line?

Comment: They are memory addresses.

Comment: Converting `0x1` to an `int *` might be undefined behaviour. Avoid undefined behaviour. Yes. Avoid me.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Converting `0x1` to `int *` is undefined behaviour? Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It gives you the address of these variables, i.e. their memory location.

You have these variables, which are function arguments, but they're just like any other local variable in the testPointer function:

```
 int testPointer(int * intArray, int * ptr)
                       ^^^^^^          ^^^
```

They live somewhere in memory, and you get the address of that location with the & operator
.
This is similar to doing

```
int i;
printf("%p\n", (void*)&i);
```

which shows the address of the `i` variable.

Note that you should use %p to print a pointer, as in `printf("%p\n", (void*)&ptr);`, %i or %lu expects an int or long argument, which might not be compatible with a pointer on a given platform.

> What do they represent and why is the last line always four less than
>   the third line

This is because the compiler have placed those 2 variables adjacent to each other in memory, and on your platform a pointer is apparently 4 bytes big.

And we might also guess from this that on your platform, arguments to a function are placed on the stack from left to right (first `intArray`, then `ptr`) if the stack on your system grows downwards in memory(which is the most common)

Comment: `printf("%p\n", &ptr);` is wrong, too. See [Question 5.17](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Oh you mean without the `(void*)` cast. The answer seems to have been changed so it is correct now.

Answer (score 1):

The last line is always (exactly 4 on a 32 bit system) less than the 3rd line because both variables are on the stack, which traditionally grows downwards from the top of memory.

Comment: This is an implementation detail, and is not guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: Of course, but some traditions are stronger and more prevalent than others.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Of course, but StackOverflow is forever and traditions in the IT realm change quite frequently. The C standard is here to guarantee that those changes don't affect the way our code runs.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens What is a "32-bit system"? Does my Sega Megadrive count? What about my Core i7? I intend to prove to you, by asking questions, that if neither of those can be "32-bit systems", then nothing can be.

Comment: "32-bit system" these days is more about OS than hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You don't decipher these values. They are the addresses selected by the operating system and the C memory allocation routines to hold your variables. These are the areas in memory that the system determined are available for you to use.

What more do you want to decipher?

Comment: Sounds sensible, to me. I wish I had thought to add that to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

When this function is invoked, `int testPointer(int * intArray, int * ptr)`, the values of `intArray` and `ptr` are stored in stack. Hence, `&intArray` will print a pointer which is same as stack pointer which will vary for each run of the program.

When 2 parameters are passed, each parameter is pushed into stack one above the other. Since, the 2 parameters are pushed one next to each other and size of pointer is 4 bytes, you observe the difference of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the behaviour is undefined because the `%lu` directive should correspond to a `long unsigned int` typed argument. This might be working for you, but only by coincidence. You wouldn't want to make a habit of relying upon coincidence. There are implementations where `long unsigned int` differ in representation and width to pointers, and this code could cause crashes.

If you want to print these addresses portably, you need to use the `%p` directive, which corresponds to a `void *` typed argument. Don't forget to cast the argument to `void *`, because `int *` might differ in representation to `void *`. See [Question 5.17 of c-faq.com](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html).

> How do I decipher these values?

They're addresses. Think of them like postal addresses. When the repossession guys want to retrieve financial assets, they go to the address of the person and take the TV. When the delivery man wants to deliver a parcel, he locates the person by following the address. This is conceptually similar to the way common processors retrieve and store values on computers (in a very basic way).

> What do they represent ...

They *might* represent the offset of the objects they point to. For example, when `&intArray` corresponds to `3212962484`, that *might* be an indication that `intArray` is located at the 3212962484th byte in your RAM. Relying upon this would be coincidental, however. The way you're printing pointers isn't portable, and pointers are conceptually distinct from integers. They might also be your credit card numbers.

> ... and why is the last line always four less than the third line?

Coincidence, or a choice the people who designed your compiler, OS or CPU made. Four might also be [the percentage of answers that fully respond to double-barreled questions](http://survey.cvent.com/blog/cvent-web-surveys-blog/online-survey-pitfalls-double-barreled-survey-questions).

Answer (score -1):

Those two lines are the addresses of the pointers in memory. (you should use `%p` to display them).

Since they are two consecutive `int*` passed to the function, they are `sizeof(int*)` = 4 bytes apart (on a 32-bit system).

Comment: What's "a 32-bit system"? Does my quad-core i7 count?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue it means that your program uses [32 bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit_application) = 4 bytes for its memory addresses. A quad-core i7 should support [64 bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) addressing but maybe you are using a 32 bit operating system or software.

Comment: What if I use a cross-compiler to build 32-bit code? What if I install a 32-bit OS onto my quad-core i7? If I have a DSP processor where `CHAR_BIT` is 16, is a 32-bit integer still *4 bytes*?

Comment: What if [`sizeof (int *)` is different to `sizeof (void *)`](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html)? Which number do I use, then? Don't core i7s use 36-bit address spaces? I thought they were labelled as 64-bit processors because they have at least one 64-bit register, rather than bus size or address space.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour if your OS is 32bit or you compile the program that way, it will be executed as such. Every pointer is simply a memory address, therefore, every pointer type is of the same size. All core i7s (i.e., their memory addresses and instructions) are 64 bit.

Comment: Your first sentence answers three of my questions, and you might want to revise it against your answer. Keep in mind, C was not designed exclusively for Intel. Sooner or later, you'll learn that lesson. If you want sooner, so that you don't make so many mistakes based on incorrect assumptions, find the link in my questions and click on it. -1 because you're not describing C, but a programming language that is similar to C which differs in subtle and possibly devastating ways.

Comment: With my original answer, I was addressing the OP's question, which did not mention any special or historical hardware; my assumption was x86 (or similar). To be more precise: 32 bit code (or OSs) runs on x86-64 CPUs due to backwards compatibility; afaik, i7s are labeled 64 bit for their instruction set and address space (register and bus sizes can be larger).